# Allow SimpleElastix version and official version of SimpleITK package exists but import with different names

Tags: python, simpleitk

I am currently developing an medical image Follow-up system which requires to use registration function provided in SimpleElastix version of SimpleITK (Modified SimpleITK 2.0.0), however, I will also need to use some functions only in SimpleITK 2.2.0.

SimpleElastix: https://simpleelastix.github.io/

Is there any method that maybe I can build the SimpleElastix version to a different name so that I can import both version??

Answer (score 0):

If you build the source code yourself, you can enable the SimpleITK_USE_ELASTIX CMake variable.  Then SimpleElastix will be built in to SimpleITK.

v2.2.0 was the first SimpleITK release that includes the Elastix source code.  However the binary Python packages are not built with Elastix enabled.  Thus you need to build it from source.